# How to give the Constraints for the UIImageView besides the UITextField?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout

I have the SignIn Page where we need to put the UIImage (Say Mobile Number) besides the UITextField. So the constraints which i am putting is like this:

For Mobile Number

UIImage: Leading to the container, Width and Height, Horizontal spacing to UITextField

UITextField : Trailing to the Container, Vertical spacing to the UIImageView for Profile Picture, height and width.

Similarly For Password

UIImage: Leading to the container, Width and Height, Horizontal spacing to UITextField

UITextField : Trailing to the Container, Vertical spacing to the UITextField (Mobile Number), height and width.

But still the constraints are not getting satisfied with the Iphone for all the screens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have only one thing wrong...

Do **not** set width constraints on your `UITextFields`.

The Horizontal Spacing from image to textfield sets the "left edge" of the textfield, and the textfield's Trailing to the Container constraint sets the "right edge" of the textfield.

So, on different width screens, the textfield will stretch to fill the space.

Comment: i tried but still its crashes. It shall be helpful if you provide me with a sample github code for this to understand the basic autolayouts.

Comment: Is your app *crashing*? Or are the elements just not showing up where you want them?

Comment: yess... i mean are the elements just not showing up where i want them

Comment: Please help me with a sample github project... It shall be rather helpful for me...

Comment: Can you post your storyboard with image resources to a github project? That would make it easy for me to grab it and adjust the constraints so you can see the difference.

Comment: what constraints do you set for icons??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146105/discussion-between-donmag-and-jessica-thompson).